# db request firebase with react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

please can you help me to write this request in a new firebase notation please

```
useEffect(() => {
  let unsubscribe;
  if(postId){
    unsubscribe =db
    .collection("posts")
    .doc(postId)
    .colection("comments")
    .onSnapshot((snapshot)=>{
      setcomments(snapshot.doc.map((doc)=>doc.data()))
    })
  }
  
  
}, []);
```

best regards

im trying to write it but i dont how can i use "db.doc"
im writing somthing like that

```
useEffect(() => {
    onSnapshot(
      collection(db, "posts", "comments"),(snapshot) =>
        setcomments(
          snapshot.docs.map((doc) =>
            post: doc.data())
        )
    );
  }, []);
```

but it's not work

Answer (score 1):

The following should do the trick:

```
import { collection, onSnapshot } from "firebase/firestore";

const col = collection(db, "posts", postId, "comments");
const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(col, (snapshot) => {
  // ...
});
```

More details on how to declare sub-collections with the JS SDK v9 in this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-define-the-collectionreference-of-a-subcollection-in-javascript-sdk-v9-c0ffb0459695).

Comment: Did you import the `collection()` method? `import { collection, onSnapshot } from "firebase/firestore";`

Comment: of corse my friend

Comment: Don't name your variable `collection` as it conflicts with the function of the same name